# Rounded corners on input in Firefox looking weird

Tags: html, css, firefox

Check this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dzdk79pk/). Tested in IE11 and latest Chrome, all looking fine. But Firefox (currently v32) messes it up. I tried adding -moz-border-radius:28px; but it makes no difference.

```
<div class="searchbox">
  <input id="searchInput" onkeypress="zoekArtikel(event);" type="text">
</div>

.searchbox{
    width:265px;
    height: 37px;
    background-color: #000d59;
    margin-left:40px;
    margin-top:90px;
}

#searchInput{
    width:203px;
    margin-left:10px;
    margin-right:10px;
    margin-top:7px;
    height:20px;
    -moz-border-radius:28px; /* makes no differnce */
    border-radius:28px;
    padding-left:5px;
    padding-right:35px;
    background-size: 25px 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `border: 0;` to `#searchInput`

Comment: That does the trick! Thanks, I'll accept as soon as possible.
Is it possible to do this for Firefox only (something like -moz-border: 0; ) ? I kinda like the border in the other browsers...

Comment: You could also try `border-style: inset outset outset inset; border-width: 1px;` if you do want a border in Firefox.

Comment: @misterManSam that gives back the problem I mentioned.

Comment: Really? Maybe we are thinking of different problems... here is [my example](http://jsfiddle.net/kj12ow6p/1/), background removed :)

Comment: Did you check that in Firefox? It gives the same problem here...Here a screenshot I took from your jsfiddle in Firefox => http://itreflex.be/roundedcornersFirefox.jpg